# Change calendar language magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, calendar

How can I change the language of Magento's frontend calendar? Its a DHTML Calendar so that I can configure it in many ways. But I cant find out any multi-language options. Is there any way?

Comment: The core Magento JS calendar is multilingual by default . Isn't it working for you?

Comment: Can you notify how could I set an another language in default magento calendar?

Comment: What what text for example?

Comment: for months and days

Answer (score 1):

The most of calendar translations are located in `Mage_Page.csv` file of your locale. However some variable stuff like months and weekdays are generated dynamically by `Zend_Locale_Data` class and can not be easily overwritten.

See `Mage_Core_Block_Html_Calendar::_toHtml()` for more info.

The quick solution would be to copy your `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/[your-locale].xml` to `app/code/local/Zend/Locale/Data/[your-locale].xml` and modify it there but still not a very clean solution.